# 3d libraries like threejs or babylonjs and onboard video memory not working?

Tags: html, webgl, gpu, babylonjs

I`ve used babylonjs for a demo project, then run it on a laptop without dedicated video memory and it does not show anything...it`s just blank screen. I know that webGL use the GPU, so is there a solution to display my project for thoose users with onboard video memory? Or I must create a fallback version?

And if so, how to detect if user`s video memory can`t support webGL?

Comment: This has nothing todo with the GPU using shared or dedicated memory. Either the GPU you were trying on is not supported or you're using features that the GPU does not support.

Comment: well the animation is pretty simple http://hariga.ro/test/nicu.html  I don`t think I`ve used so advanced features not beeing able to run it...The main reason for not showing that, I think, is because the video memory is too low, 16MB RAM approximately, obviously onboard memory...

Comment: Your application is *"only"* using 5MB of graphics memory(which is still an insane considering the complexity of your scene). When the GPU has only 16MB of memory its probably too old to support WebGL.

Comment: @Gigi Ionel did you check if opengl is supported? Is there anything in console? it is hard to help without any debug message

Comment: type "`about:gpu`" into the url bar in Chrome and it will tell you if it's supported

Comment: I`ve checked again and now its runnig, I have made no change to the laptop, but the animation its running very slow...comparing with a dedicated video memory...so webGL has a problem with those kind of laptops...in my opinion...webGL is supported because I use Chrome browser, the last version